# ImageAI understadning output

Tags: machine-learning, imageai

Running ResNet with help of ImageAI. I can't understand why there is two sets of data under each epoch.
What does it mean 10/10 and 111/111. Why model saving coming before finishing this epoch?
There is totally no information in the manual.

```
Using Enhanced Data Generation
Found 442 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 38 images belonging to 2 classes.
JSON Mapping for the model classes saved to  /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/images/ML/json/model_class.json
Number of experiments (Epochs) :  100


Epoch 1/100
10/10 [==============================] - 22s 2s/step - loss: 7.6561 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.50000, saving model to /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/images/ML/models/model_ex-001_acc-0.500000.h5
111/111 [==============================] - 297s 3s/step - loss: 0.7466 - acc: 0.7941 - val_loss: 7.6561 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 2/100
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 7.6561 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 00002: val_acc did not improve from 0.50000
111/111 [==============================] - 12s 105ms/step - loss: 0.3910 - acc: 0.8778 - val_loss: 7.6561 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Comment: I think 1 progress bar is for training phase and 1 progress bar is for validation phase.

Comment: @JodhSingh, thanks, it makes sense